# Django 1.11.4 : django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm learning how to do web programming with Django framework and I got this error message when I try to create an instance of my `Artist` from my `app models`. I use Python 3.6 version and Django 1.11.4 version.

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File ".\app\models.py", line 9, in <module>
        class Artist(models.Model):
      File "C:\Users\kadjo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DatabaseFun\DatabaseFun\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in __new__
        app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
      File "C:\Users\kadjo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DatabaseFun\DatabaseFun\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
        self.check_apps_ready()
      File "C:\Users\kadjo\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\DatabaseFun\DatabaseFun\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
        raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
    django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Answer (score 1):

**First** add these lines on top of your settings.py file.

```
import django
django.setup()
```

**And then** if this doesn't work try to remove third-party applications from your installed apps list one-by-one. You can again load them later, It may be because of dependency on certain third-party apps.

Answer (score 0):

this is my models package code

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("artist", max_length=50)
    year_formed = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("album", max_length=50)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist)
```

this is my app setting package code

```
"""
Django settings for DatabaseFun project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import posixpath

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ec5ea5b6-ee2d-43db-8bb8-4562d88788ea'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app',
    # Add your apps here to enable them
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'DatabaseFun',
]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'DatabaseFun.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'DatabaseFun.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you running this code? If you are running it standalone, then you must use django.setup().

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/#calling-django-setup-is-required-for-standalone-django-usage